# Use of padding-bottom method to normalize column height gives error with use of name anchors

Tags: css

Would very much appreciate some assistance with this issue. I use the following common css method to make column sizes equal across two columns:

```
.wrap {
            overflow:hidden;
}    
.leftside {
            float:left;
            width:50%;
            height:auto;
            background:blue;
            padding-bottom: 32768px;
            margin-bottom: -32768px;
}
    .rightside {
            float:right;
            width:50%;
            height:auto;
            background:red;
            padding-bottom: 32768px;
            margin-bottom: -32768px;
}
```

This works well provided the page is not called with a URL containing a name anchor, which totally screws up the display. Is there anything I can do to keep the name anchor reference from changing the display, while still maintaining equal column heights?

Here is a link to an example page showing links with and without name anchor:

http://trifectas.org/test.html

Comment: Uhg! That looks like an ugly hack...You could use faux-columns or even jQuery. It be more elegant and maintainable.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree :) However, my example is a simplification of the same issue in a site built on Drupal and in this case I don't want to change anything other than css.

Comment: what exactly you want I am confused here :(

Comment: why you are using padding bottom this much ;o

Comment: I want to be able to link to an name anchor referenced inside a column and have it NOT throw the overflow display out of whack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a rather detailed treatise on my issue at [this site](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/appendix/equalheightproblems#linking). It seems that there is no solution that will work in all browsers and and the remedy is far worse than the original problem. The final thought was to just eliminate the use of name anchors, which is what I ultimately did.

Answer (score 0):

removing the margin-bottom from the right side seems to fix it when playing in firebug, not sure if that'll have a knock on effect to your code though.

Comment: Thanks, but does not cure it in the main application. It results in the right column not extending to same length of left column.